# Bidirectional mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, bidirectional, hibernate-onetomany

I have two tables, quotation and quotation_item. There is one to many relationship them. My requirement is when I do `quotation.setQuotationItem(set)`, old quotationItem mapped to quotation should get removed and quotationItems in set should get mapped against quotation.

/*********   My Quotation pojo is like ************/

```
    public class Quotation {
    int quotationId;
    String code;
    String clientName;
    Set<QuotationItem> quotationItem=new HashSet<QuotationItem>();
    //getter and setter
    }
```

/*********       QuotationItem POJO **********/

```
    public class QuotationItem extends Quotation{
    int id;
    Quotation quotation;
    String itemName;
    int rate;
    int qty;
    //getter and setter
    }
```

/********        Quotation.hbm ****************/

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.paramatrix.pojo.Quotation" table="quotation" >
    <id name="quotationId" type="int" column="quotation_id">
    <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="code" column="code" type="string" />
    <property name="clientName" column="client_name" type="string" />
    <set name="quotationItem" table="quotation_item" cascade="save-update" inverse="true">
    <key>
    <column name="quotation_id" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="com.paramatrix.pojo.QuotationItem" />
    </set>
    </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

/****    QuotationItem.hbm  ************/

```
    <class name="com.paramatrix.pojo.QuotationItem" table="quotation_item" dynamic-insert="true">
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
    <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="quotation" class="com.paramatrix.pojo.Quotation" >
    <column name="quotation_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="itemName" column="item_name" type="string" />
    <property name="rate" column="rate" type="int" />
    <property name="qty" column="qty" type="int" />
    </class>
```

My tables structure is like for 
Quotation

`quotation_id` `code` `client_name`

My table structure for Quotation_item

`id` `quotation_id` `item_name` `rate` `qty`

Comment: @Taylor If I put 3 quotationItem in a Set<QuotationItem> and then assign that set to Quotation.setQuotationItem(set).
Next time when I put 2 different quotationItem in a Set & then assign that set to Quotation then these two new quotationItem are also get mapped with Quotation. BUT I WANT ONLY LAST TWO QUOTATION ITEM GET MAPPED WITH QUOTATION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify the set rather than replace it. i.e.:

```
    quotation.getQuotationItem().clear();
    quotation.getQuotationItem().addAll(newSet);
```

This is due to some hibernate weirdness.

Aside, a small point about naming.  Your `Quotation.quotationItem` should be named `quotationItems` as it contains more than one `QuotationItem`.

Comment: You can take a look on my code from this link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/grrkv6kj6ad3xmb/ParentChildHibernateDemo.rar

Comment: Hi @Taylor, ur suggestion worked fine but for audit log purpose i am using findDirty() method of hibernate interceptor. In that method, value of old set(quotationItem) and new set(quotationItem) is being same. If i remove ur logic, it show difference. Any work around ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `findDirty() method of hibernate interceptor` can you update your question with the code?